# Fourier transform of a product in two dimension

Tags: convolution, fourier-transform

I am actually interested in a more specific case than the title.

Let Fourier transform of $f(\vec{x}^2)$ be $\mathcal{F}[f](t)$:

More specifically,
$\mathcal{F}[f](t) = \int \frac{d^2 \vec{x}}{(2\pi)^2} \exp(-i\vec{x}\cdot\vec{t}) f(\vec{x}^2)$.

(Note that I have intentionally wrote $f(\vec{x}^2)$ to show that f is a function that depends only on the magnitude of $x$).
If I do know the form of $\mathcal{F}[f](t)$, what is then $\mathcal{F}[f \times \ln \frac{\vec{x}^2}{k^2}]$?

where $\times$ is just a trivial product and $k$ is a constant.

I suppose this is some general two-dimensional convolution theorem, but I am not really exactly sure about the specific form of the generalized convolution theorem or the fourier transform of $\ln \frac{\vec{x}^2}{k^2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is well known that $-\frac1{4\pi}\ln(x^2+y^2)$ is a fundamental solution of the Laplace equation on the plane and that it's inverse Fourier transform "should be" $|\xi|^{-2}$. Note that both functions are not integrable in $\mathbb R^2$. In Vladimirov V.S., *Equations of mathematical physics*, $\S9.7$, distribution
$\cal P\frac1{|x|^2}$, 
$$
\left(\cal P\frac1{|x|^2},\varphi\right)=
\int_{|x|<1}\frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{|x|^2}\,dx+
\int_{|x|>1}\frac{\varphi(x)}{|x|^2}\,dx
$$
is discussed and proven that
$$
F\left(\cal P\frac1{|x|^2}\right)=-2\pi \ln |\xi|-2\pi C_0, 
$$
where $C_0=\gamma -\log (2)$.
The FT is defined there as
$$
\int e^{i \xi x} f(x)\,dx
$$
So one should modify constants accordingly. 
From there it is possible to express $\ln|\xi|$, find $\mathcal F[\ln|\xi|]$ and get 
$$
\mathcal{F}[f \times \ln \frac{\vec{x}^2}{k^2}]=
\mathcal{F}[f \times \ln \vec{x}^2]-\ln k^2\mathcal{F}[f]=
$$
$$
\mathcal{F}[f ]*\mathcal{F}[\ln|x|]-\ln k^2\mathcal{F}[f].
$$
The resulting formula should work at least for smooth functions $f$ with compact support.

Comment: Two questions. 1.) you have both $\ln \zeta$ and $\ln x$. Are you using them consistently? 2.) The FT you wrote is in 1d and thus convolution is in 1d too. Could you be little more explicit in 2d for me? Thank you.

Comment: 1) $\xi$ is the argument of $\cal F$. But according to Vladimirov's definition $\cal F^{-1}[f](\xi)=(2\pi)^{-2}\cal F[f](-\xi)=(2\pi)^{-2}\cal F[f](\xi)$ since functions in question are even. 2) Everybody in the answer it's a two dimentional FT:  $$ \int_{\mathbb R^2}  e^{i (\xi, x)} f(x)\,dx.$$

Comment: So f(x) dx in your integral is really x = \vec{x}?

Comment: Yes $~~~~~~~~~$